# Import passwords from Safari to Chrome

Tags: password, google-chrome

I am just switching from Safari to Chrome in my MacBookPro and first thing I did was to import bookmarks from Safari.
Now I would also like to import passwords from websites, logins etc.

In *Chrome > Settings > Sign In > Advanced Sync Settings*, I have already checked every available sync option, however just google account passwords have been imported, not Safari's.

[image]

I also tried *Chrome>Import Bookmarks and Settings>From Safari>Import*, but still no results.

Does anyone know how to import Safari/Keychain passwords to Chrome?

Answer (score -3):

I Think these depend on you Gmail account or which account you used for Sync your passwords... so in chrome you just add you same Gmail or other account and you get your Sync password automatically.